# C#: splitting a class into multiple files (with a form)

Tags: c#, file

Using: C#, VS2008

I have the following main form class:

**[Main.cs]**

```
namespace Server
{
   public partial class PipeServerform : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

But it's big, and long, and contains GUI + logic code.

So I seperate the class into multiple files for easier management and create this file that only holds the logic details:

**[DoCommands.cs]**

```
namespace Server
{
   public partial class PipeServerform : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

This works... ***BUT!***  The '*DoCommands.cs*' file within the VS2008 project now has a default blank GUI 'form' window associated with it.

It makes sense, as it's still part of the main form class, but I assumed the separation between different files would inform VS2008 that it is simply a logic file holder of simply commands, and doesn't contain any GUI form code.

Is there an easy way to solve this view?  Such that the '*DoCommands.cs*' file doesn't have the associated blank GUI form with it?

Or do I have to literally split it into different classes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If order to get it to subordinate itself under PipeServerForm, open the project file in a text editor. You will find a block looking like this:

```
<Compile Include="DoCommands.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Change it into this:

```
<Compile Include="DoCommands.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Main.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Now, when you load the project, `DoCommands.cs` should appear under `Main.cs`, just as `Main.Designer.cs`. I did note that VS seem to add the `SubType` element automatically, so that `DoCommands.cs` will still open in the Forms Designer by default. Perhaps there is a simple solution around for that as well.

Comment: When I re-load the solution, VS2008 reinserts the '<SubType>Form</SubType>' text back into the project file for the 'DoCommands.cs' lines, and the GUI blank form still exists within it.  But at least it's listed under the 'mainform.cs' tree within the project file.  I guess that's the best we can hope for.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you don't have to specify all inheritances for a partial class. So if you just drop System.Windows.Forms.Form from the inheritance list for the DoCommands.cs file you should be golden.

**Edit**: Also, given the size of your main form, you might want to consider refactoring. Consider following a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) pattern. Separate your concerns into separate classes and possibly even modules.

Comment: Nope.  Removing 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' from the DoCommands.cs file did not change anything.  VS2008 still marks it with a GUI form icon and treats it as such.   :(
And while I do agree that refactoring the design to use MVC, et al., is the better way, for now time limits hinder a complete redesign of such.

Answer (score 2):

I used inheritance rather than partial implementation to split a form features across several files without getting that blank designer form when opening the secondary file.

**[MainForm.cs]**

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Form")]
public partial class MainForm : MainFormFeature
{
...
}
```

**[MainForm.Designer.cs]**

```
partial class MainForm
{
...
}
```

**[MainForm.Feature.cs]**

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MainFormFeature: Form
{
...
}
```

Then, as mentioned above, edit your project file and add the following for your Feature file to show up next to the Designer in your solution explorer.

```
<Compile Include="MainForm.Feature.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MainForm.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

It's the only solution I could find to make it work nicely in Visual Studio without getting that blank designer form. It probably also makes sense from an object design point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Your partial form extension don't need to inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Form - just like your PipeServerform.designer.cs do not inherit it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above solutions worked for me in VS2019, however the following IMO is a good workaround:

In your .csproj file find the

```
<Compile Include="DoCommands.cs" />
```

(or something similar) and modify it to

```
<Compile Include="DoCommands.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Main.cs</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Compile>
```

This ensures that when you double-click on your DoCommands.cs file in the solution explorer, it opens up as code. It also puts the DoCommands.cs file under the Main.cs in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Apr 06,2023:

OK, this is an old question, but a much simpler solution works for me with VS2019-VS2022:

In Solution Explorer, add a class to the project named DoCommands.

in DoCommands.cs, replace the line

```
class DoCommands
```

with

```
public partial class PipeServerform : System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

This module is now a part of the original PipeServerform class. I think this is much less hassle than hand-editing the project source.